# Cybersource Payment Gateway set multiple redirect url

Tags: php, payment-gateway, omnipay

I am having issues with cybersource payment. I am using omnipay for cybersource. The issue is that my site has multiple locations where payments are collected like while adding credit in the account there is a separate url, while registration page is different therefore my action and redirect url will be dynamic.

My question is that do I need to create multiple profiles and assign it for every page where payments are collected or is there any parameter available like in Paypal to redirect the user back to our site after payment page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello @Sandeep J Patel You can override the redirect and cancel url just by passing the overriding parameter for cancel and response pages. So you need not to create multiple profiles for the same and all you need to pass is the url that you wish the user to redirect after arriving from the payment page. Please refer the following document for the same.

You can take advantage of the “override_custom_receipt_page” field within Secure Acceptance instead of having multiple profiles. Please [take a look here in the documentations][1] for additional information.

[1]: http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_SOP/Secure_Acceptance_SOP.pdf

Answer (score -1):

> My question is that do I need to create multiple profiles and assign it for every page where payments are collected

Yes, you do.  If I were you I would be lobbying Cybersource support to add the return URL and cancel URL as a separate parameter for the transaction but at the moment they do not support it.  More and more gateways are adding these parameters -- I recently had discussions with the support team at MultiCards in the Netherlands and they added these parameters to their existing API after I explained the need for them.

Comment: thx for the response. Can you let me know how can i set up 3d secure in cybersource. Is there any library or code available for reference